# C: Using two-dimensional arrays with function pointers

Tags: c, arrays, function-pointers

I need to use a number of functions pointers with an additional boolean flag.
I've tried the following, but it will not compile.
Can anyone help?

```
int handler1(int mix) {
    ...
    return 0;
}
int handler2(int mix) {
    ...
    return 0;
}
int handler3(int mix) {
    ...
    return 0;
}

typedef int (*my_handler)(int mix);

typedef struct {
    my_handler handler,
    bool mix_handler,
} handle_pair;

static handler_pair handlers[] = {
    { handler1, FALSE },
    { handler2, TRUE },
    { handler3, FALSE },
    { NULL, FALSE },
};
```

Comment: First of all, what errors do you get? Second, in C there is no native type `bool`, do you include `<stdbool.h>`?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's these lines that give you a problem:

```
typedef struct {
    my_handler handler,
    bool mix_handler,
} handle_pair;
```

You should end declarations with `;`, even in structs. Like this:

```
typedef struct {
    my_handler handler;
    bool mix_handler;
} handle_pair;
```

Also, you typedef the name `handle_pair` but declare the array with type `handler_pair`. "Handle" or "handler"?

Answer (score 1):

Your struct typedef is wrong, you separate declarations with semicolons, not commas in a struct declaration, as in normal code.

It should be:

```
typedef struct {
    my_handler handler;
    bool mix_handler;
} handle_pair;
```

If I comment out the ... lines, and stick the following at the head of the file:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
```

And change `handler_pair` to `handle_pair` in your static declaration, it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <cstdio>

int handler1(int mix) {
    //...
    return 0;
}
int handler2(int mix) {
    //...
    return 0;
}
int handler3(int mix) {
    //...
    return 0;
}

typedef int (*my_handler)(int mix);

typedef struct {
    my_handler handler;
    bool mix_handler;
} handle_pair;

static handle_pair handlers[] = {
    { handler1, false },
    { handler2, true },
    { handler3, false },
    { NULL, false },
};
```

and next time show the errors and specify the compiler, operating system etc. This was tested with VisualC++ 9

Comment: Please, the question is tagged C and not C++

Comment: But does C contain `bool` data type?

Comment: C99 has `bool` if you include `stdbool.h`. If you don't, it only has something called `_Bool`.